# Putting curly braces in a sentences for specific words according to their start and end indexes

Tags: java

I need to put curly braces in a sentence according to the indexes. Suppose my input sentence is: `"I am a girl and I live in Nepal."` and I need to put curly braces according to

```
[12, 15], [2, 4], [23, 25]
```

These indexes are corresponding to the words `"am"`, `"and"` and `"in"` respectively.
The required output should be:

```
"I {am} a girl {and} I live {in} Nepal."
```

I have tried using `substring` but after it replaces first word, it then shifts the characters by two indexes and that is the problem I am having.

Can anyone provide me solution to get the required output?

Comment: Try doing it starting from the highest index and going towards the lowest.  I.E.  Do it backwards.

Comment: You can also split the string into parts, add the braces and assemble the parts into a new string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would:

1. split the original string into [characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).
2. iterate through and write each char to a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
3. before you write each char, check if the index of that char corresponds to a starting brace position, and if so write a starting brace to the StringBuilder
4. after you write each char, check if the index of that char corresponds to an end brace position, and if so write a end brace to the StringBuilder

The above doesn't modify your original string (or rather the string that you're working with). It builds a new string up from the original chars, char-by-char.

Answer (score 1):

I think simple `String.substring` on that indices with a `String.replace` should work.

Here's the code for one of the indices - `[2, 4]`: -

```
String str = "I am a girl and I live in Nepal.";

String str2 = str.replace(str.substring(2, 4), "{" + str.substring(2, 4) + "}");
System.out.println(str2);   // str is not changed.
```

**OUTPUT: -**

```
I {am} a girl and I live in Nepal.
```

If you don't know that indices, but only have the words, then you can find that out using `String.indexOf` method.

Here's the better solution: -

```
    String str = "I am a girl and I live in Nepal.";

    int startIndex = str.indexOf("am");
    int endIndex = startIndex + "am".length();

    str = str.replace(str.substring(startIndex, endIndex), 
                "{" + str.substring(startIndex, endIndex) + "}");

    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Yes, you are rightRohit.But doing this will modify the original sentence by 2 index which is a problem.

Comment: @SuneetaSingh. Then make new String and assign to it.

Comment: @SuneetaSingh.. Check out. I added one more code. That would work. It finds the index of the word first. So, change in length would not matter.

Answer (score 0):

- Sort your parameter array
- Validate that for each entry, the endpoint is gte the begin
- Validate that for each entry, the begin is gt the end of the last entry
- Loop over the characters, appending them to a `StringBuilder` as you go
- If, while looping, you encounter the begin or end of an entry, set the appropriate brace before or after the character